# Compare the properties of two PsCustomObjects

Tags: powershell, pester

I know that I can compare the **values**  of two PowerShell objects:

```
PS> $A = [PsCustomObject]@{"A"=1; "B"=$True; "C"=$False}
PS> $B = [PsCustomObject]@{"A"=1; "B"=$False; "C"=$False}
PS> Compare-Object $A $B -Property A, B, C

A  B     C SideIndicator
-  -     - -------------
1  False False =>
1  True  False <=
```

However, I need to compare the existance the **properties** of two PowerShell objects.

These objects would be considered the same:

```
PS> $A = [PsCustomObject]@{"A"=1; "B"=$True; "C"=$False}
PS> $B = [PsCustomObject]@{"A"=1; "B"=$False; "C"=$True}
PS> Compare-Foo $A $B
True
```

These objects would be considered NOT the same:

```
PS> $A = [PsCustomObject]@{"A"=1; "C"=$False}
PS> $B = [PsCustomObject]@{"A"=1; "B"=$False; "C"=$False}
PS> Compare-Foo $A $B
False
```

Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: `!@(Compare-Object @($A.PSObject.Properties) @($B.PSObject.Properties) -Property Name).Length`

Comment: @PetSerAl, that worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of a few ways to do this, the most straightforward but not really tested:

```
$A.Keys | ForEach-Object { $C = $B["$_"]; if ($C -eq "") {return $false;} }
```